# RabbitTemplate receive and requeue

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I would like to receive messages from a queue an immediately dequeue them, in fact I would like to mimic the behaviour of the rabbitMQ admin console which can receive a message and requeue it.

So my question is how to do this? At first I was trying to make a clone of the message and re-send them, but it seems that the rabbitTemplate is not able to send messages directly to a queue and sending them to an exchange is not an option because it could be possible that multiple queues will receive the message again.

Then I started thinking that I could receive a message and then somehow NACK it so that it ends up back on the queue. The only question there is how should I do that?

Comment: So you want to route a message from one queue to another?

Comment: No @Zarathustra. I want to take a message from a queue and then immediately put it back. much like what the rabbit admin GUI is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve that with `basicReject`:

```
public class MyListener implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {

   public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
        //Do something with message
        channel.basicReject(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), true);
   }

}
```

Comment: That's what I eventually ended up doing. Thx for the response

Comment: @Artem, but your solution uses a listener. I'm having a similar problem and I want the consuming and requeueing to be a single action, not repeatable by the listener. So that a user clicks a button and sees the messages in the queue, but the queue doesn't lose them. Just like in the Rabbit Admin UI.

Comment: See there answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890701/rabbittemplate-receive-messages-and-requeue.

Comment: Yep, it was me who created that one:-)