# RabbitTemplate receive messages and requeue

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

My question is very similar to this one:
[RabbitTemplate receive and requeue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876178/rabbittemplate-receive-and-requeue)
Unfortunately it has been marked as answered though the answer doesn't suit my needs.

I want to mimic the functionality of the Rabbit Admin UI, i.e. I want to synchronously read messages from a queue, but don't want the queue to lose them, i.e. something like having a peek.

The answer here [RabbitTemplate receive and requeue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876178/rabbittemplate-receive-and-requeue) suggests using a listener, but in that case it'll read and requeue indefinitely. I want to get and requeue the messages just once, so I guess I should be using RabbitTemplate, not a listener.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Peeker implements ChannelCallback<Message> {

    final MessagePropertiesConverter propertiesConverter = new DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter();

    @Override
    public Message doInRabbit(Channel channel) throws Exception {
        GetResponse result = channel.basicGet("someQ", false);
        if (result == null) {
            return null;
        }
        channel.basicReject(result.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), true);
        return new Message(result.getBody(), propertiesConverter.toMessageProperties(
                result.getProps(), result.getEnvelope(), "UTF-8"));
    }
}
Peeker peeker = new Peeker();


...


Message peek = this.rabbitTemplate.execute(peeker);
```

Comment: @GarryRussel, looks good. But how can I get N messages (or all the messages)? Should I invoke basicGet in a loop until I get null?

Comment: Yes, and you can reject them all with one call to `basicNack` (instead of `basicReject`) - obviously change the return type to `Collection<Message>` or similar.